# Unexpected behavior of Json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to create a Json, in which a question have value, option and also it contain multiple questions. and these sub questions can also contain multiple sub questions.

here is my Json string

```
   {
  "Questions": {
    "question": {
      "Value": " Quest 1",
      "Option": " Quest 1 Option",
      "question": {
        "Value": " Quest 2",
        "Option": " Quest 2 Option"
      },
      "question": {
        "Value": " Quest 3",
        "Option": " Quest 3 Option",
        "question": {
          "Value": " Quest 4",
          "Option": " Quest 4 Option",
          "question": {
            "Value": " Quest 5",
            "Option": " Quest 5 Option"
          },
          "question": {
            "Value": " Quest 6",
            "Option": " Quest 6 Option"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But when I'm trying to see it in Json Viewer,ques 2 and ques 5 is missing. 
what I'm doing wrong here ?

Comment: hi, give us more context... what is "json viewer"? what structure do you expect?

Comment: I have paste This json  here [Json viewer](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON shows as valid here, although I think your structure isn't exactly what you intended:

http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

You might want to consider making "Questions" an array of objects, just seems like it would be a little cleaner.

For example, I find this much more readable:

```
{
    "Questions": [
        {
            "Value": " Quest 1",
            "Option": " Quest 1 Option",
            "questions": [
                {
                    "Value": " Quest 2",
                    "Option": " Quest 2 Option"
                }
            ]
        },        
        {
            "Value": " Quest 3",
            "Option": " Quest 3 Option",
            "questions": [
                {
                    "Value": " Quest 4",
                    "Option": " Quest 4 Option",
                    "questions": [
                        {
                            "Value": " Quest 5",
                            "Option": " Quest 5 Option"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "Value": " Quest 6",
                    "Option": " Quest 6 Option"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hello. thanks for your answer. Now I have another problem . How to read this Json as It may any level of childs 
See this Json [My Json](http://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/50fa6d).

How to use `$.each` loop so that I can read this json.

Comment: You would have to use a recursive function call to iterate through each level

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for an array syntax, like this:

```
{"Questions":[
    {"question":{"Value":" Quest 1 "}},
    {"question":{"Value":" Quest 2 "}}
]}
```

Note the square brackets indicating the array.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple keys on the same object...

there are two each of these:
Questions.question.question and
Questions.question.question.question

An object is like a dictionary, there can only be one uniquely named key in each object. You may want to consider using arrays.

Comment: @Locgemage:Now I'm using array ,but now unable to read this json. 
[My Json](http://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/50fa6d). How to read this Json.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, according to your link, that is valid json. It reads it just fine.

Comment: I want to loop over it . I'm confused here, as It may have many sub level, so I don't know at which level need to check using `$.each` loop.